# How do I parameterize template blocks in knitr?

Tags: r, knitr

Say I have the following code in knitr. How can I run it multiple times with different values of i?

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
i<-0.1
```

### X,Y plot of Y=X+e where e is a standard normal distro: mean=0, sd=`r i`

```{r, echo=FALSE}
r<-rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=i)
x<-seq(0,1,length.out=100)
y<-x+r
plot(x,y)
```
````

**EDIT:**

As has been suggested ... I tried to do something like this: start a loop in an R code block, have a template in between and then close the loop -- R throws and error.

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
for (i in 1:4) {
```

# bla 

```{r, echo=FALSE}
}
```
````

Comment: You could [reuse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080793/reusing-chunks-that-include-plotting-with-knitr-rmd) the chunk, but why don't you just loop over these 4 lines of codes multiple times?

Comment: precisely ... how do I loop over the heading -- that was kinda my question --

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the point initially. I thought `### X,Y plot ...` was meant as R comment and missed that it's a markdown heading. Context matters … See my answer (soon).

Comment: @CL, many thanks -- looking forward to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes this question tricky is that not only the chunk content (the plot) must be repeated, but the heading as well. That's why we can neither simply [reuse the chunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080793/reusing-chunks-that-include-plotting-with-knitr-rmd) nor just loop over the plot command like

```
for (i in 1:3) { plot(rnorm(100, sd = i)) }
```

But it's almost that simple: We loop over the code that produces the plot and output the heading from inside the loop. This requires the [chunk option](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#text-results) `results="asis"` and `cat` to get verbatim markdown output:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, results = "asis"}
sdVec <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)
for (sd in sdVec) {
  cat(sprintf("\n### X,Y plot of Y=X+e where e ~ N(0, %s)", sd))
  r<-rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=sd)
  x<-seq(0,1,length.out=100)
  y<-x+r
  plot(x,y)
}
```
````

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36808845/2706569) for related issues.